# How to fill RSS feeds in datagrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I am using .net c# and i want to fill datagrid with rss feed.

Problem is

When i return rss feed in to dataset then i got multiple table wich storing diffrent data.

Means i want to fill grid with "Title" and "Picture" here is my code example

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(txtUrl.Text); 
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   ds.ReadXml(reader);
   myDataGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[2] ; 
   myDataGrid.DataBind(); 
}
```

All the details regarding Title and description and posted date is sitting in tables #2 and related image and size of image related information is stored in table #3 so how can i feel grid with this two column ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you try the [RSS Tookit](http://www.codeplex.com/ASPNETRSSToolkit). It's open source and handles RSS feed nicely. You can easily bind to a RSS feed like this:

```
<ast:RssDataSource id="RssDataSource1" runat="server" maxitems="5" url="http://news.google.com/?output=atom"></ast:RssDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="RssDataSource1">
  <Columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="link" DataTextField="link" HeaderText="Link"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="title" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Source taken from [this page](http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Consuming%20With%20RssDataSource&referringTitle=Home).

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could just use the in-built **XmlDataSource**.

```
<asp:XmlDataSource id="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" XPath="/channel/item" DataFile="rssFeed.xml" />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="title" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I know the example I've given is for a GridView, but I think the same principle applies to DataGrids. The XPath expression assumes RSS 2.0.